# What is the radius of gyration when the axis of rotation passes through the centre of mass

Tags: rotational-dynamics

"Radius of gyration is defined as the distance from the axis of rotation to a point where the total mass of the body is supposed to be concentrated, so that the moment of inertia about the axis may remain the same. Simply, gyration is the distribution of the components of an object. It is denoted by K."

Now ,
1) If the axis of rotation passes through the centre of mass (where the total mass of the body is concentrated), is the radius of gyration zero?

I found an answer in the comment section in YouTube, but I'm not sure I understand. It says that after rotating, you have to recalculate the moment of inertia and the radius of gyration in that direction relative to the y-axis.

2) But why recalculate ? And why the y-axis?

Comment: -An example can be a thin ring whose  center of mass is at the center of the ring...if one calculates MI about an axis passing through the center perpendicular to the plane of the ring it will come out to be mass x radius square..if you find radius of gyration then it is r^2. what did we learn...its not zero. It means keeping the axis intact rotate an equivalent mass at r distance from the axis.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is incorrect as you have stated.

It is not zero, but only a minimum when axis is passing through CM.

This is because there are particles of physical mass that are away from the mathematically defined line axis through CM, as $\int r^2 \, dm = k^2 \,m. $

If we rotate about a parallel axis, we add a term $m h ^2$ making total moment of inertia $ m(k^2+h^2). $

If $h=0$ we still have the central mass.

For moment of inertia to be zero the mass of object has to be zero!

EDIT

As an example  integration of an odd function area is zero, but when squared the volume of squared function is non-zero.

Comment: If we rotate with the Centre of Mass as the axis, the Centre of Mass does not move, right? So, we cannot decompose the motion of the rotating body into the motion of the centre of mass. As a result is the mass concentrated at some other "point" so that we can decompose the motion of that body to the motion of that "point ? If so can you please tell be what that "point" will be?

Comment: So, do we take some other point close enough to the Centre of Mass so that we can say that:(a) the total mass will be concentrated at that point and (b)the radius of gyration will be a minimum ??

Comment: By idealization all particles are at a point. But really particles are at some distance.